# Power BI remove duplicates based on max value

Tags: powerbi, business-intelligence, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, data-transform

I have 2 column; ID CODE, value

[image: (this is my column)]

Remove duplicates function will remove the examples with the higher value and leave the lower one. Is there any way to remove the lower ones? The result I expected was like this.

[image: result I expected]

I've tried Buffer Table function before but it doesn't work. Seems like Buffer Table just works with date-related data (newest-latest).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `SUMMARIZE` which can be used similar to a SQL query that takes a `MIN` value for a column, grouped by some other column.

In the example below, MIN([value]) is taken, given a new column name "MinValue", which is grouped by IDCode.  This should return the min value for each IDCode.

```
NewCalculatedTable = 
SUMMARIZE(yourTablename, yourTablename[IDCode], "MinValue", MIN(yourTablename[value]) )
```

Alternatively, if you want the higher values just replace the `MIN` function with `MAX`.

Comment: how can I keep the rows based on specific value not MIN?